# "Timed out waiting for device" during boot after reinstalling bootloader

Tags: boot, mount, grub

I installed Windows 10 alongside Zorin OS 16.1 and accidentally deleted Grub. I installed the Grub bootloader again by using a recovery drive. The Grub bootloader issue is now fixed, but my boot time has increased.

My boot time was **15s** to **20s**. And now it is about **1:30min** to **2:00min**. I checked the boot logs, and I found this. This was why it was taking so long.

**MY BOOT LOGS**
[image]

```
/dev/nvme0n1p7: clean, 544873/4571136 files, 10764430/18277376 blocks
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/D653-89B5.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/D653-89B5.
```

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

1. This is my `/etc/fstab` file data (commented lines are not included).

   ```
   UUID=d5419a27-3b88-4985-b9a8-1307da7fddf3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

   UUID=D653-89B5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
   /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

   /dev/disk/by-uuid/24E0E53BE0E51438 /mnt/Data auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
   ```

   I tried to change the number next to `errrors=remount-ro 0` to `0` and `2`. But it does not change anything.
2. I tried to boot from a live USB and run this command:

   ```
   sudo fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p7
   ```

Nothing worked for me. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.